# Magento2- Custom attribute customer not show in admin

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, customer-attribute

I have added custom attribute of customer, It have added to database but not show in backend.

I have used

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php bin/magento  cache:flush –all

  But still not show.I have added below code:
  [image]

Please help me!

Comment: where it does not showing?

Comment: please confirm your module Onlinebiz_CustomerTrade has been enabled or not from config.php (or else) you check in db setup_module table also?

Comment: It not show in customer edit https://prnt.sc/i2494v . I have checked in db have had  version https://prnt.sc/i249yh

Comment: Hi jordan do not show your extensions file path everyone notify what is your work. Hide them if important !!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code', [
            'type' => 'static',
            'label' => 'Label Name',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
            'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
            'option' => ['values' => ['Text1', 'Text2','Text3','Text4','Text5']],
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'customer_account_edit'
                ],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

You can edit 'used_in_forms' info according to your need . May be you dont'n need first option in the array .

Comment: Thank you help me!  
I will try it!

Comment: Hi Shashank Gupta,I have added your code. It has show but When save, It not save in db.

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :) made my day